# Navigation bar making main divs appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the home div disappear and the about page appear but for some reason I can't get it to work. it is for a navigation bar and if I can get one working I can get them all so pleas help. I need home to disappear when I press the about paragraph and make the about div appear. I hope someone can help me I have googled a lot and it just won't work.

```js
// page movement 
function goA() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("about").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.home {
  background: #4f4f4f;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.backgroundpic {
  background-image: url("http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/58/58/hlVdYW.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 93.7%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about {
  font-family: Open sans;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
}

.about a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, .7);
}

.about {
  font-family: Open sans;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150%;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 18.4%;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--  home div  -->
<div class="home">
  <div class="backgroundpic">
    <div class="picgradiant">

      <!--  navigation button  -->
      <div class="navigation">
        <div class="navloc">
          <p class="loc" onclick="goW()">WebDesign</p>
          <p class="loc" onclick="goGr()">Photography</p>
          <p class="loc" onclick="goS()">SketchUp</p>
          <p class="loc" onclick="goSh()">Photoshop</p>
          <p class="loc" onclick="goA()">About</p>
          <p class="loc" onclick="goH()">Home</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stripes">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--  text about myself  -->
      <div class="totalheader">
        <div class="headtext">
          <p class="header1">Sup, I'm Lars.</p>
          <p class="text1">I do things!</p>
        </div>
        <p class="buttonhead">click to lear more</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--  about div  -->
<div class="about">
  <p>I like to explore different programs and try out as many things as I can. I do this so I can make an informed, good and fun career choice! A lot of projects start with me and my friend talking and getting an idea. Eventually we try to make it happen,
    but sometimes help altogether and sometimes us work together. my goal at the moment is the become a game developer, but I am also interested in game design and internet security. I am not sure what the future holds for me, but in the end, I hope that
    I'll have a fun job. If you want more info you can contact me at: <a href="mailto:larsmulleneers@hotmail.nl">Larsmulleneers@hotmail.nl</a> </p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of results.  Even if there is only 1 result you still have to access it by index.  Try  `document.getElementsByClassName("home")[0].style.display="none";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
 document.getElementsByClassName
```

returns an array not element so you can't change the element without the index number
try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByClassName('about')[0].style.display = 'block'
```

Comment: i have this in total maby you can spot the problem. it still isn't working for me maby it is the the program i am using (brackets)

Comment: no brackets is perfect but maybe you did something wrong

Comment: i posted a anser above the code wont fit in a comment

Comment: can you send me all the code and I will edit it and resend it to you again

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: upload it in a codepen or jsfiddle and i will fork it and send you the new link after editing

Comment: I knew the problem
It was a mistake from me
I wrote `document.gtElementsByClassName`
instead of `document.getElementsByClassName`
I will edit it in the  answer
just add `document.getElementsByClassName`
and everything will work well

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one element using the same className and `document.getElementsByClassName` return more than one results which is an array.

Either you can access the very first element or use id to make them unique.
Check the example below which I created for you:

```css
 #home {
   background: #4f4f4f;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
 }
 
 .backgroundpic {
   background-image: url("http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/58/58/hlVdYW.jpg");
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 93.7%;
   margin-left: 50px;
   margin-right: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<body>

  <li onclick="aoG()">Home</li>
  <li onclick="goA()">About</li>

  <!--  home div  -->
  <div id="home">
    <div class="backgroundpic">
      <div class="picgradiant">

        <!--  navigation button  -->
        <div class="navigation" onclick="rotatebar(this)">
          <div class="navloc">
            <p class="loc" onclick="goW()">WebDesign</p>
            <p class="loc" onclick="goGr()">Photography</p>
            <p class="loc" onclick="goS()">SketchUp</p>
            <p class="loc" onclick="goSh()">Photoshop</p>
            <p class="loc" onclick="goA()">About</p>
            <p class="loc" onclick="goH()">Home</p>
          </div>
          <div class="stripes">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--  text about myself  -->
        <div class="totalheader">
          <div class="headtext">
            <p class="header1">Sup, I'm Lars.</p>
            <p class="text1">I do things!</p>
          </div>
          <p class="buttonhead">click to lear more</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  about div  -->
  <div id="about">
    <p>I like to explore different programs and try out as many things as I can. I do this so I can make an informed, good and fun career choice! A lot of projects start with me and my friend talking and getting an idea. Eventually we try to make it happen,
      but sometimes help altogether and sometimes us work together. my goal at the moment is the become a game developer, but I am also interested in game design and internet security. I am not sure what the future holds for me, but in the end, I hope
      that I'll have a fun job. If you want more info you can contact me at: <a href="mailto:larsmulleneers@hotmail.nl">Larsmulleneers@hotmail.nl</a> </p>
  </div>

<script>
  function goA(){
    document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";
  }
  function aoG(){
   document.getElementById("home").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
</body>
```